# Silencing cucumber stack trace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, stack-trace, bdd

Does anybody know how to silence or filter lines from the backtrace of a cucumber run? Im running a rails 2.3.5 App with the database_cleaner plugin set to truncate after each scenario. And every time one runs, the terminal gets flooded with useless "NOTICE truncate cascades.. blah blah" message.

I've tried using the config/initializers/backtrace_silencers file but as far as I can see it doesn't really affect the messages put on screen during test runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to find edit your postgresql.conf file, set "client_min_messages = warning", and reload postgres.

Answer (score 0):

This messages are coming from your database log.
consider changing your database config to suppress NOTICE warnins.